# Jenkins container persistence on Kubernetes cluster - PersistentVolumeClaim (VMware/Vsphere)

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, vmware, vsphere, volumes

Trying to persist my jenkins jobs on to vsphere storage when I delete the deployments/services.

I've tried using the standard approach: used StorageClass, then made a PersistentVolumeClaim which is referenced in the .ayml file that will create the deployments.

storage-class.yml:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: mystorage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
parameters:
  diskformat: zeroedthick
```

persistent-volume-claim.yml:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc0003
spec:
  storageClassName: mystorage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 15Gi
```

jenkins.yml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-auto-ci
  labels:
    app: jenkins-auto-ci
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: jenkins-auto-ci
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-auto-ci
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins-auto-ci
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins-auto-ci
        image: jenkins
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        ports:
        - name: http-port
          containerPort: 80
        - name: jnlp-port
          containerPort: 50000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: jenkins-home
          mountPath: "/var"
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc0003
```

I expect the jenkins jobs to persist when I delete and recreate the deployments.

Answer (score 0):

You should create [VMDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMDK) which is Virtual Machine Disk.

You can do that using [govc](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/tree/master/govc) which is vSphere CLI.

`govc datastore.disk.create -ds datastore1 -size 2G volumes/myDisk.vmdk`

Or using [ESXi CLI](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.vcli.migration.doc_50/cos_upgrade_technote.1.4.html) by ssh into the host as `root` and executing:

`vmkfstools -c 2G /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/volumes/myDisk.vmdk`

Once this is done you should create your PV let's call it `vsphere_pv.yaml` which might look like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0001
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  vsphereVolume:
    volumePath: "[datastore1] volumes/myDisk"
    fsType: ext4
```

The `datastore1` in this example was created in root folder of vCenter, if you have it in a different location you need to change the `volumePath`. If it's located in `DatastoreCluster` then set `volumePath` to`"[DatastoreCluster/datastore1] volumes/myDisk"`.

Apply the yaml to the Kubernetes by `kubectl apply -f vsphere_pv.yaml`

You can check if it was created by describing it `kubectl describe pv pv0001`

Now you need PVC let's call it `vsphere_pvc.yaml` to consume PV.

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc0001
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Apply the yaml to the Kubernetes by `kubectl apply -f vsphere_pvc.yaml`

You can check if it was created by describing it `kubectl describe pvc pv0001`

Once this is done your `yaml` might be looking like the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-auto-ci
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins-auto-ci
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins-auto-ci
        image: jenkins
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        ports:
        - name: http-port
          containerPort: 80
        - name: jnlp-port
          containerPort: 50000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: jenkins-home
          mountPath: "/var"
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc0001
```

All this is nicely explained on Vmware GitHub [vsphere-storage-for-kubernetes](https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-storage-for-kubernetes/blob/master/documentation/persistent-vols-claims.md).